# how to start osixia/openldap image with volumes mounted?

Tags: docker, openldap, docker-volume

I am running **osixia/openldap and osixia/phpldapadmin** (volumes mounted) with these commands :

```
docker run -p 389:389 -p 636:636 --name ldap-service --volume /data/slapd/database:/var/lib/ldap --volume /data/slapd/config:/etc/ldap/slapd.d  --hostname ldap-service --detach osixia/openldap:1.2.3 --copy-service --loglevel debug

docker run --name phpldapadmin-service --hostname phpldapadmin-service --link ldap-service:ldap-host --env PHPLDAPADMIN_LDAP_HOSTS=ldap-host --detach osixia/phpldapadmin:0.7.2
```

On the first run it starts but on restarting the servers with the same command I got the error

```
 - /container/run/startup/slapd failed with status 34
 - whereas status 34 refers to  LDAP_INVALID_DN_SYNTAX
```

could not be able to find a solution for this. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

If you look at the document, you will find error 34 stands for invalid `DN`.

When you initialize your ldap server with docker, if startup script did not find your `LDAP_BASE_DN` environment variable, it will generate one from `LDAP_DOMAIN`, for example, `LDAP_DOMAIN="xxx.com"` will lead to `LDAP_BASE_DN="dc=xxx,dc=com"`.

But if you stop your container, and start another one with old volume mounted, startup scirpt will not generate `LDAP_BASE_DN` from your `LDAP_DOMAIN`, when you look at debug log, you will find it is starting up with an empty `DN`. That is exactly why it won't start normally.

So the solution is clear: set `LDAP_BASE_DN` every time, if you use a docker-compose file, just add it to your "environment" section.

Comment: well they have released new update but i have also used your solution and it worked for me